# How to use string as classname and call it in a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, web

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('table tr td a').click(function (event) {
             alert(event.target.id);
             var ClassName = event.target.id;
             var Pref = '.'
             var ClassFull = Pref + ClassName;
             var TdText = $(ClassFull).text();
             alert(TdText);
         });
     });
 </script>
```

MARKUP :

```
    <p>
        Account No:
        <input id="AcctNo" type="text"/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
    <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
           <tr>
              <td>
                 <a id ="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployerName)" 
                    href ="#">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployerName)</a>
              </td>
              <td class = "@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployerName)" >
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AcctNo)
              </td>
           </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

i get the id of the sender and have a td with the classname same as the id of the sender, then get the text inside it. doesn't seem to return the text that i wanted to get

Comment: can the employer name can have spaces or special characters

Comment: You should **never** use display or edit templates inside other elements.  Please include the source code your browser recieves and you'll see why...

Comment: Reduced indentation a little to bring it back into view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that the problem is probably because of spaces in the EmployerName but here are a couple other ways to go about getting your data.

Notice I moved the click event handler to the tr tag. You can use the html5 data attribute to store any information on any html tag.  Or you can access the text like you were doing.

```
<p>
    Account No:
    <input id="AcctNo" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       <tr>
          <td class="EmployerName" 
                data-name="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployerName)" 
                data-acctno="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AcctNo)">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployerName)
          </td>
          <td class="AcctNo" >
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AcctNo)
          </td>
       </tr>
    }
</table>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('tr').click(function (event) {
             var TdText = $(this).find('.EmployerName').text();
             var Td2Text = $(this).find('.AcctNo').text();
             var Td3Text = $(this).find('.EmployerName').data('acctno');
             alert(TdText);
         });
     });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I assume is, `employerName` can have spaces and special characters which would change the meaning of the selector.

In this case you want the text of the clicked element's parent's next sibling so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table tr td a').click(function (event) {
        var TdText = $(this).parent().next().text();
        alert(TdText);
    });
});
```

---

Or you can use predefined class names like

```
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a class="employer-name" id ="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployerName)" href ="#">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployerName)</a>
            </td>
            <td class = "acctNo" >
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AcctNo)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

then find the parent's(`td`) sibling with class `acctNo` like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table a.employer-name').click(function (event) {
        var TdText = $(this).parent().siblings('.acctNo').text();
        alert(TdText);
    });
});
```

Comment: You're right sir, it was because of the special characters.